# How to join application data with Cognito User Pool + Cognito Identity Pool users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

If I have a Cognito User Pool and a Cognito Identity Pool and I have application specific data, is there anything considered best-practice in how to join these together?

For example, supposing I have application data stored in DynamoDB, perhaps SMS/text messages sent by a user. Also supposing a text message (as stored in the DB) looks like this:

```
{
    "account_id": "a-uuid-for-the-account",
    "message_body": "Hello world",
    "message_subject": "Greetings!",
    "date_sent": "...",
    "message_id": "..."
}
```

Would I then join this to the User Pool or the Identity Pool? For example a separate accounts table might have records resembling this:

```
{
    "account_id": "a-uuid-for-the-account",
    "user_pool_username": "MrBloggs"
    "addresses": [ "123 Springfield Road", "Blahsville" ]
}
```

I can see disadvantages of joining to the User Pool, as you may introduce other IDPs and this would then fail. So perhaps, you would use the ID of an Identity Pool 'identity'?

Lastly, this question makes me wonder what the point of the 'attributes' are that you might store against the User Pool users (in the user pool itself)? Taking the postal address example as used above, if this were stored in the User Pool then you'd have to store addresses for users in other IDPs separately — duplicating effort and complicating the software.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use Cognito user pools as a provider for your Cognito identity pool, which would then give you credentials to access Dynamo.

If you're using multiple providers, the approach that would probably make the most sense is to use the Cognito identity pool's generated id (identity id) as the key in Dynamo, as the user may only log in with some public provider, not user pools.

This identity id is constant once a login is linked, with one exception. If two authenticated identities merge in an identity pool, the resulting identity id could be either. Since Dynamo works the way it does, this would mean you would have to catch merge events, then grab all entries from Dynamo that exist for the old key, delete them, and re-insert them with the new key. This is admittedly not the smoothest scenario, and we'll take this as a feature request to make this use case a bit easier.

Storing data against a user isn't really designed with Cognito federated identities (identity pools) in mind, only user pools. It really makes the most sense when user pools is more of a stand alone entity, not as much in the use case you described.

Comment: does the Cognito identity pool's generated id (identity id) can be uses as a Primary Key in DynamoDB tables? Is this the recommended behavior ?

Comment: The *only* time an identity id for an authenticated id will ever change is in case of an identity merge. If identity a has user pools authentication and identity b has facebook, say you give identity a's user pools token and identity b's facebook token with identity a - that will trigger a merge. The resultant identity id could be either a or b, it's random.

Comment: So, if you might merge, it could change, otherwise no. If you're using user pools, the sub field is a unique identifier for that user and could also be used.